# Sheets - How to check if more than one specific word exists in a range

Tags: google-sheets, string-matching

In Google Sheets I want to create an alert in cell D17 with the text "match" when a lookup in a range D5:D15 includes both text strings as a match, "Oil" and "Water" from a list of text.

Screenshot of current sheet:
[image]

Comment: Please share an example (even a screenshot) of how the values in each of your cells are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following formula

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(D5:D15,"oil")>0,COUNTIF(D5:D15,"water")>0),"match","no match")
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`COUNTIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480)
- [`AND`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)

Comment: _Just a thought_. You could probably make the title more user friendly as well. Like: _"How to check if more than one specific words exist in a range"_.